# Keepalived vIP as Galera wsrep_cluster_address

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

I have a MariaDB Galera cluster.
If some nodes fail, I cannot blindly restart them, I have to determine a good `wsrep_cluster_address` first.

If I can keep a keepalived virtual IP on one of the healthy nodes, can I use this IP as `wsrep_cluster_address` on other nodes? So in case of node failure, the joining node would always have a right `wsrep_cluster_address`? Or are there any other solutions enabling automatic rejoin?

I feel it should be somehow possible to keep the cluster up and automatically rejoin nodes as long as there is at least 1 healthy node (or `Primary Component`?) up.

(Note: I am aware of the answer in [Galera cluster without having to specify all hosts on wsrep_cluster_address](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147142/galera-cluster-without-having-to-specify-all-hosts-on-wsrep-cluster-address), but multicast is unfortunately not an option.)

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple addresses into `wsrep_cluster_address`, e.g. `gcomm://10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2,10.1.1.3`, and Galera Cluster will detect it smartly.

I has used Percona XtraDB Cluster (which is based on Galera Cluster too) to run serveral (> 10) clusters in production environment:

- One has been running with 2 DB servers and 1 garbd server, and we put all three servers into `wsrep_cluster_address`.
- Another was 7 database servers, and we just put first three servers (which were in different racks) into `wsrep_cluster_address`.

There were power failures (all three servers), hardware failures, software bugs on these clusters in four years, and they worked pretty well.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I need.
The only problem is, if the cluster changes, I have to update the `wsrep_cluster_address`es on all nodes and this is something I want no avoid.
Say I have 3 nodes. If I dismantle 2 of them and replace them with 2 new nodes, I cannot blindly restart the one survivor node without changing its config.
I could live with that, but it would be nice to have one config for all nodes and forget.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out and yes, it seems to work.

### Test setup:

**3 nodes.**

One dynamic (DHCP) IP on each node's `eth0`.

The nodes are hostnamed: `mari0`, `mari1`, `mari2`, and these names are resolvable. (May not be needed, but...)

`wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://1.2.3.4'` on all 3 nodes. (Note: the first node must be started with `wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://'`, after the cluster is up, wsrep_cluster_address` should be changed to the vIP.)

A keepalived vIP on the nodes.

```
! Configuration File for keepalived
vrrp_script chk_mysqld {
    script "pidof mysqld"
    interval 2
}
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state [MASTER|BACKUP]
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 52
    priority [PRIO]
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type AH
        auth_pass [password]
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        1.2.3.4
    }
    track_script {
        chk_mysqld
    }
}
```

(not the best, but works)

### First result:

After the first node was started, the vIP was placed on it. After that I started the remaining 2 nodes.

The nodes joined the cluster and their `keepalived`s entered `BACKUP` state.

`service mysql stop` removed the node from the cluster, `service mysql start` added the node to it.

I did not tested adding a 4th and 5th node to the cluster this way, yet, but it should also work.